# Using .npy files as input/data for CNN network

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to feed my network greyscale npy arrays with the dimensions 160 x 160. I am having trouble altering the dimensions so I using ImageDataGenerators for this but the images are not validating.

The X_col is dataset column of the absolute filepaths of all the npy files (which contain the image arrays). The y_col is the dataset column of the float spin value.

```
train_images = train_generator.flow_from_dataframe(
dataframe=train_set,
x_col='Image Array',
y_col='Spin',
target_size=(160, 160),
color_mode='grayscale',
class_mode='raw',
batch_size=32,
shuffle=True,
seed=42,
subset='training'
```

"Found 0 validated image filenames.
Found 0 validated image filenames.
Found 0 validated image filenames."

Comment: The error says nothing about dimensions; it's all about file names.

Comment: ImageDataGenerator does not support .npy files, as they are not a standard image format.

Comment: [You need to use `flow()`, not `flow_from_dataframe()`.](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow) You also need to pass actual arrays, not filepaths.

Comment: As per the documentation, input takes a Numpy array of rank 4 or a tuple. If tuple, the first element should contain the images and the second element another numpy array or a list of numpy arrays that gets passed to the output without any modifications. Do an np.reshape on your input date to get it resolved